# Converting incoming Date in PHP

Tags: php, date

How can I convert a date from a format like this `13/Février/2016` to `2016-02-13` (Y-m-d) ?

Comment: Please ask two questions for your two topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to transform the month to English or a numeric value.

then all of the above answers will work

```
$month_name=array("","Janvier","Février","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin","Juillet","Août",
"Septembre","Octobre","Novembre","Décembre");

$dateinput = '13/'.array_search("Février",$month_name).'/2016';
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $dateinput)));
echo $date;
```

Comment: Y ist index is empty?

Comment: To make it equivalent to month number

Comment: one and the same thing depends on how you want to do it.

Comment: Yes its solution and in Hindi called jogar. ;)

Comment: Welcome but you can have a check as you said that site can have date in english to so you can put a check in_array before this

Comment: @nasri_thamer did u chk strftime()??

Answer (score 0):

You need to reformat the datestring using the DateTime class, see below for the answer.

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('DD/m/YY', $dateString);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: i have done this before but it display me this error :  Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean

Answer (score 0):

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('DD/m/YY', $dateString);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: you can see the respone of Grabit and i tell him the error with this script

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:)

```
<?php
$changedate = str_replace("/","-","13/February/2016");
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($changedate));
?>
```

Comment: it display 1970-01-01 :(

Comment: Because of February to Février check your server laungauge it might be french

Comment: You just change February to  Février in my code it will work for you

Comment: no this is just an example but the date like 13/Février/2016 is coming from a form and the website sometimes in english sometimes in frensh by the client because it is multilang

Comment: <?php

if($language=="french")
{
$month_name = "Février";
}
else if($language=="English")
{
$month_name = "Feburary"; 
}

$changedate = str_replace("/","-","13/".$month_name."/2016");
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($changedate));
?>

Comment: i have 12 months in 5 languages ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)** and **[`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)** for other language.

```
$date = "13/Février/2016";
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR'); 
echo strftime("%Y-%b-%d", strtotime($date));
```